# Appease Your Google Overlords: Draw the "G" Logo

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output, geometry

Write a program or function that takes in a positive integer N, and outputs an N×N pixel image of Google's ["G" logo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg) according to this* construction:

> [image: "G" logo construction]

For example, if N is 400, a 400×400 pixel logo should be output, with correct dimensions and colors:

[image: "G" logo 400x400 example]

It should look accurate regardless of how large or small N is. e.g. here is N = 13: [image: "G" logo 13x13 example]

Your code should not need to connect to the internet. For example, scaling an externally hosted svg is not allowed. (Scaling an svg encoded in your code would be fine though.)

Anti-aliasing may be used or not. It's up to you.

Notice that the horizontal bar of the "G" does not extend all the way to the right edge of the image. The circle curves normally inward on the right edge before it is cut off.

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

---

<sup>** The construction of the logo has been simplified for this challenge. The correct construction can be seen [here](https://g-design.storage.googleapis.com/production/v6/assets/article/evolving-the-google-identity/g-letter.mp4) and [here](https://design.google.com/articles/evolving-the-google-identity/).*</sup>

Comment: Is there a minimum N? A 1x1 image would likely produce unrecognizable output regardless of how good the solution is.

Comment: @jpmc26 N is a positive integer, so minimum 1. Of course a 1x1 image can't be recognizable, but "It should look accurate" meaning, e.g. a black image wouldn't make sense, even at that scale.

Comment: What's the expected output for a 1x1 image, then? A single pixel of any of the colors in the image? A white image? What about 2x2? There are still more colors in the image than pixels for that size. If any image is unacceptable at those scales, the challenge should define what is and is not acceptable, since you *cannot* produce an image even coming close to the correct appearance, shouldn't it? (If it were my challenge, I'd exclude them to keep it simple, but your decision. You would also need to verify that you don't exclude existing answers with the new specifications, I think.)

Comment: @jpmc26 No. People can use common sense to tell if a 1x1 or other small image looks accurate.

Comment: Are we permitted to download a pre-made `.svg` and encode it into our solution, or do we have to originally make it?

Comment: We need a TikZ answer!

Answer (score 58):

## Mathematica, <s>229</s> <s>226</s> <s>225</s> <s>224</s> <s>221</s> <s>206</s> 169 bytes

Thanks @MartinEnder for 1 byte, @ChipHurst for **37 bytes!**

```
Graphics[{RGBColor@{"#EA4335","#FBBC05","#34A853","#4285F4"}[[#]],{0,-1}~Cuboid~{√24,1},Annulus[0{,},{3,5},{(2#-9)Pi/4,ArcCsc@5}]}&~Array~4,ImageSize->#,PlotRange->5]&
```

What a fun challenge!

## Explanation

```
...&~Array~4
```

Iterate from 1 to 4...

```
RGBColor@{"#EA4335","#FBBC05","#34A853","#4285F4"}[[#]]
```

Convert the color hex codes to `RGBColor` objects, so that they can be applied to the Google logo graphic. Change the color palette to the `<input>`th color.

```
{0,-1}~Cuboid~{√24,1}
```

Create a filled rectangle (2D cuboid), whose diagonal corners are (0, -1) and (sqrt(24), 1).

```
Annulus[0{,},{3,5},{(2#-9)Pi/4,ArcCsc@5}]}
```

Generate four filled quarter-`Annulus`s, centered at the origin, with inner radius 3 and outer radius 5. Do not draw past `ArcCsc@5` (where the blue segment ends).

```
Graphics[ ... , ImageSize->#,PlotRange->5]
```

Create a graphic with size N x N, from x = -5 to x = 5 (removes the padding).

## Outputs

N = 10

[image]

N = 100

[image]

N = 200

[image]

N = 10000 (click image for full resolution)

[image]

Answer (score 45):

### C (Windows), 311 bytes

```
#include <windows.h>
main(int c,char**v){float x,y,a,b,N=atoi(*++v);HDC d=GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());for(x=0;x<N;x+=1)for(y=0;y<N;y+=1){a=2*x/N-1;b=2*y/N-1;SetPixel(d,x,y,(a>0&&a<.8&&b*b<.04)?0xF48542:(a*a+b*b>1||a*a+b*b<.36)?0xFFFFFF:(a*a<b*b)?((b<0)?3490794:5482548):(a<0)?376059:(b<-.2)?0xFFFFFF:0xF48542);}}
```

Takes "N" as command line argument and draws directly on the screen.

Un-golfed:

```
#include <windows.h>
// atoi() will work fine without any #include file!
// -> don't #include it!

main(int c,char **v)
{
    float x,y,a,b,N=atoi(*++v);

    /* Access the screen for directly drawing! */
    HDC d=GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());

    /* Iterate over the pixels */
    for(x=0;x<N;x+=1)
        for(y=0;y<N;y+=1)
    {
        /* Convert x,y into "relative" coordinates: The image
         * is 2.0x2.0 in size with (0.0,0.0) in the center */
        a=2*x/N-1;
        b=2*y/N-1;

        /* Draw each pixel */
        SetPixel(d,x,y,
            (a>0 && a<.8 && b*b<.04)?0xF48542: /* The bar of the "G" in the middle */
            (a*a+b*b>1 || a*a+b*b<.36)?0xFFFFFF: /* Not on one of the circle segments */
            (a*a<b*b)?((b<0)?0x3543EA:0x53A834): /* Top and bottom segments */
            (a<0)?0x5BCFB: /* Left segment */
            (b<-.2)?0xFFFFFF:0xF48542); /* Right segment: A bit more complicated... */
    }

    /* Note: Under good old Windows 3.x we would require to
     * call "ReleaseDC" here; otherwise the system would
     * "crash" (however the image would have been drawn!)
     * No need for this in modern Windows versions! */
}
```

Comment: You could keep `0xF48542` and `0xFFFFFF` in integers.

Comment: What compiler/linker did you use? Doesn't work with mingw

Comment: @vsz Presumably, Visual Studio's compiler.

Comment: @vsz I can compile it with `gcc g.c -lgdi32` on mingw.

Comment: Why use `x+=1`? Floats have `operator++`. Also, `a,b` will never reach `2.0` since `x` only goes up to `N-1`. You should divide by `N-1`.

Comment: @KarlNapf Thanks. I thought `operator++` would only work with integers.

Comment: @TuukkaX In the original code I used hexadecimal (for better readability). Only in cases where decimal was shorter than hexadecimal (including the leading `0x`) I replaced hexadecimal by decimal.

Comment: @MartinRosenau I was vague in my comment :D I meant keeping the values in variables.

Comment: you have to add 3 bytes for the /TC switch :*)

Comment: With your loops like this `for(x=0;x<N;x+=1)` could you not shorten them to something along the lines of `for(x=0;N>++x;)`

Comment: Also I think in C `0xFFFFFF` can be shortened `2**24-1`, I might be wrong though

Comment: `-1>>8` may also work

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw No `**` exponent operator in C :(

Comment: I'm not sure whether you missed my comment about keeping the large hexadecimals in integers and then using them. Should save a few bytes.

Comment: @TuukkaX you're right my bad! However I think `~0` would be `0xFFFFFF` in hex, that would save him 12 bytes in this code (assuming ~0 auto casts to hex, I'd bet it does I can't test this though because I don't have windows.h on my mac)

Answer (score 35):

## Python 2, <s>244</s> 220 bytes

using Martin Rosenau's transformation on the [-1,1]^2 plane and minor golfing like removing `0.` or brackets

```python
N=input()
R=[2*z/(N-1.)-1for z in range(N)]
B="\xFF"*3,"B\x85\xF4"
print"P6 %d %d 255 "%(N,N)+"".join([B[0<x<.8and.04>y*y],["4\xA8S",B[y>-.2],"\xFB\xBC\x05","\xEAC5"][(x>y)+2*(-x>y)]][.36<x*x+y*y<1]for y in R for x in R)
```

Explanation:

```python
N=input()
R=[2*z/(N-1.)-1for z in range(N)]
#N*N points on the [-1,1]^2 plane

B="\xFF"*3,"B\x85\xF4"
#white and blue

print"P6 %d %d 255 "%(N,N) + "".join(
#binary PPM header
 [
  B[0<x<.8and.04>y*y],
  #blue rectangle part of the G, or white
  ["4\xA8S",B[y>-.2],"\xFB\xBC\x05","\xEAC5"][(x>y)+2*(-x>y)]
  #[green, [white,blue], yellow, red]-arcs with 4 way selector
 ]
 [.36<x*x+y*y<1]
 #radius checker, outside=0 blue rectangle or white, inside=1 colored arcs
  for y in R for x in R
  #for all points
 )
```

Output as binary PPM, usage:

```python
python golf_google.py > google.ppm
```

### Examples

- 13

[image: 13]

- 50

[image: 50]

- 100

[image: 100]

- 1337

[image: 1337]

#### previous 244 bytes solution

```python
N=input()
S="P6 %d %d 255 "%(N,N)
R=range(N)
B=["\xFF"*3,"B\x85\xF4"]
for Y in R:
 for X in R:y=Y-N/2;x=X-N/2;S+=[B[0<x<0.4*N and abs(y)<0.1*N],["4\xA8S",B[y>-0.1*N],"\xFB\xBC\x05","\xEAC5"][(x>y)+2*(-x>y)]][0.3*N<(y**2+x**2)**.5<0.5*N]
print S
```

#### Ungolfed beta Version before if/else elimination:

```python
N=input()
print"P3 %d %d 255 "%(N,N)
R=range
M=N/2
r="255 0 0 "
g="0 255 0 "
b="0 0 255 "
c="255 255 0 "
w="255 255 255 "
for Y in R(N):
 for X in R(N):
  y=Y-M
  x=X-M
  d=(y**2+x**2)**.5 #radius
  if 0.3*N<d<0.5*N: #inside circle
   if x>y:          #diagonal cut bottom-left to top right
    if -x>y:        #other diagonal cut
     print r
    else:
     if y>-0.1*N:print b #leave some whitespace at blue
     else: print w
   else:
     if -x>y:
      print c
     else:
      print g
  else:
   if 0<x<0.4*N and -0.1*N<y<0.1*N: #the straight part of G
    print b
   else:
    print w
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure if `1for` works.

Comment: @TuukkaX [It does.](https://repl.it/DuQP)

Comment: Can you include sample output?

Comment: @TuukkaX thanks for the `1for`
@Cyoce sample output added

Comment: All the decimals in your code that are in the form of `0.x` can be reduced to `.x` :)

Comment: @TuukkaX this is in the ungolfed beta version, the real code at the top is fine. I just posted this to show the progress from pure if/else to list/index

Comment: @KarlNapf Oh. I was accidentally looking at the previous 244 byte solution :D

Comment: You can save 6 bytes by using the actual Unicode characters `"ÿ"*3,"B…ô"` instead of hex escapes `"\xFF"*3,"B\x85\xF4"`. The escapes use up so many bytes that they're longer than non-ASCII characters in bytes in UTF-8. (NB: The `…` is actually [NEL](https://graphemica.com/0085).)

Comment: You can also save an additional 11 bytes by doing the same to `"\xEAC5"` - making it `"êC5"`, making `"4\xA8S"` → `"4¨S"`, and making `"\xFB\xBC\x05"` → `"û¼␅"`. (Once again, the `␅` is actually [ENQ](https://graphemica.com/%05).) EDIT: In Python 2, you have to declare encodings to include non-ASCII characters, so you'll need an additional 11 bytes for `#coding:u8\n` at the start. Still a loss of 6 bytes though.

Answer (score 27):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>408 ... 321</s> 317 bytes

<s>384 383 371 367 359 327 316 308</s> 304 bytes of JavaScript + <s>24</s> 13 bytes for the canvas element

```js
(f=d.style).width=f.height=(d.width=d.height=n=prompt(f.background='#FFF'))+'px';q=n/2;with(d.getContext`2d`)['#EA4335','#FBBC05','#34A853','#4285F4'].map((c,i)=>beginPath(lineWidth=y=n/5,strokeStyle=fillStyle=c,arc(q,q,z=q-y/2,(j=2*i+1)*(r=-.7854),(j+(i-3?2:1.256))*r,1),stroke(),fillRect(q,z,q*.98,y)))
```

```html
<canvas id=d>
```

1 byte saved by drawing counter-clockwise.
11 bytes saved on the HTML thanks to Conor O'Brien.
12 bytes saved using `with` block thanks to Prinzhorn.
4 bytes saved with better use of `z=q-y/2`.
8 bytes saved by using `parentNode` and `background` thanks to Alexis Tyler.
32 bytes saved by using a more precise drawing of the blue arc/bar so I don't need to erase a part of it anymore.
11 bytes saved by setting canvas css instead of its parentNode thanks to Tejas Kale.
8 bytes saved using `with` and `map` with a single statement, `2d` instead of `('2d')`, `n/5` instead of `.2*n` and initializing the background in the `prompt(...)`.
4 bytes saved replacing `Math.PI/4` by `.7854` which seems enough precision thanks to RobAu.

---

**Explanation:**

```js
(f=d.style).width=f.height=(d.width=d.height=n=prompt(f.background='#FFF'))+'px';q=n/2
```

The canvas dimensions are initilized with user input and the background is set to white. `q` is initialized.

```js
with(d.getContext`2d`)['#EA4335','#FBBC05','#34A853','#4285F4'].map((c,i)=>beginPath(lineWidth=y=n/5,strokeStyle=fillStyle=c,arc(q,q,z=q-y/2,(j=2*i+1)*(r=-.7854),(j+(i-3?2:1.256))*r,1),stroke(),fillRect(q,z,q*.98,y)))
```

For each color draws the circle part, with some adjustement for the last (blue) one. The bar is drawn for each color at the same place with the same dimensions so only the last (blue) one is visible.

Comment: `<canvas id=d></canvas>` should work, and `<canvas id=d>` might work.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I tried edge, firefox and chrome, there are doing what's needed for `<canvas id=d>` to work, hopefully other browsers do too.

Comment: You can lose another 5 chars by replacing backgroundColor with background.

Comment: Also use d.parentNode instead of d.parentElement

Comment: Why are you setting the parentNode dimensions. Just `d.style` works too. Which allows `(f = d.style).width = f.height = n = prompt() + 'px';`

Comment: Wait a sec. `(f = d.style).width = f.height = n = prompt() + 'px';` doesnt work. I thought it worked because I was reusing the older element.

Comment: @TejasKale you're right setting the style of the canvas works fine. I worked with the parentNode because it didn't seem to work with the canvas at the time.

Comment: You could use  `.785398` instead of `Math.PI/4` shaving off 2 bytes (or more if less precision is ok.

Comment: @RobAu I'm going for .7854. Since I didn't see any impacts on the 1500x1500 logo it should be fine.

Comment: ``with(d.getContext`2d`)['#EA4335','#FBBC05','#34A853','#4285F4'].map((c,i)=>beginPath(lineWidth=y=n/5,strokeStyle=fillStyle=c,arc(q=n/2,q,z=q-y/2,(j=2*i+1)*(r=-.7854),(j+(i-3?2:1.256))*r,1),stroke(),fillRect(q,z,q*.98,y)),fillRect(0,0,d.width=d.height=n=prompt(),n,fillStyle='#FFF'))`` saves 22 bytes. The `f=d.style` stuff for width and height is completely superfluous, and the `.background` part can be skipped if you call `fillRect()` instead. Other than that, everything else I left alone.

Comment: Setting the css `width` and `height` is redundant. You can just do `d.width=d.height=n=prompt(d.style.background='#FFF');` Actually setting the background is redundant as well so just `d.width=d.height=n=prompt();` That should save you 52 bytes.

Answer (score 25):

## BBC BASIC, 177 bytes

Download interpreter at http://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/download.html

```
I.n
V.19;16,234,67,53,275;64272;1468;531;16,43060;83,787;16,34114;7668;n;n;
F.t=1TO8.256S.1/n
a=t*PI/4y=n*SIN(a)x=n*COS(a)V.18;t-1>>1,25,85,x*.6;y*.6;25,85,x;y;
N.PLOT101,0,-n/5
```

BBC BASIC uses 2 units=1 pixel, so we plot a G of radius `n` units (=n/2 pixels) at centre `n,n`.

The idea is to plot a series of radial lines, changing colour as appropriate. It was found that there were small gaps between the lines due to truncation of the numbers when converted to pixels, so thin triangles are actually plotted instead.

Once the sweep of lines is completed, the cursor is at the top right corner of the blue area. A single coordinate for the diagonally opposite corner is given to draw a rectangle in order to complete the shape.

**Ungolfed**

```
INPUTn
REM reprogram pallette
VDU19;16,&EA,&43,&35,275;16,&FB,&BC,5,531;16,&34,&A8,&53,787;16,&42,&85,&F4
ORIGINn,n               :REM move origin to position n,n on screen.
FORt=1TO8.256STEP1/n    :REM from 1/8 turn to 8.56 turns in small steps
  GCOL0,t-1>>1          :REM set the colours, 0=red, 1=yellow, 2=green, 3=blue
  a=t*PI/4              :REM convert angle from 1/8 turns into radians
  y=n*SIN(a)            :REM find position of outer end of ray
  x=n*COS(a)            :REM plot to coordinates of inner and outer ends of ray
  PLOT85,x*.6,y*.6      :REM PLOT85 actually draws a triangle between the specified point              
  PLOT85,x,y            :REM and the last two points visited.
NEXT                    
PLOT101,0,-n/5          :REM once all is over, cursor is at top right corner of blue rectangle. Draw a rectangle to the bottom left corner as specified.
```

Comment: Nice work!  I did mine in Logo using a similar method before I saw your answer.  You have me beaten by about 81 bytes.

Answer (score 21):

### HTML/JS, <s>680</s> 624 bytes

**To get 624 bytes, remove the last `;`, this is needed for the snippet below due to the way it imports the HTML. Also, Firefox seems to not support `image-rendering: pixelated` and needs `-moz-crisp-edges` instead (thanks [@alldayremix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/19974/alldayremix)!) which makes a Firefox solution +7 but this does work in Chrome as expected.**

Utilises JavaScript to request `N` and a `<style>` block to position/colour the elements. Uses basic HTML elements, rather than applying styles to a canvas (which, it appears, was a much shorter approach!). This is a revamped approach using a `data:` URI background image instead of just coloured elements. I've kept the previous approach below in case this new one works on fewer browsers.

I thought this was going to be a lot smaller than it ended up being, but it was an interesting exercise nonetheless!

```html
<body id=x onload=x.style.fontSize=prompt()+'px'><u><a></a><b></b><i></i><s><style>u,a,b,i,s{position:relative;display:block}b,i,s{position:absolute}a,u{width:1em;height:1em}a,b{border-radius:50%}a{image-rendering:pixelated;background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAIAAAD91JpzAAAAFklEQVQI12N45Wzq1PqF4fceVpMVwQAsHQYJ1N3MAQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg)no-repeat;background-size:100%;transform:rotate(45deg)}b{top:.2em;left:.2em;width:.6em;height:.6em;background:#fff}i{border-top:.4em solid transparent;border-right:.4em solid#fff;top:0;right:0}s{top:.4em;right:.1em;width:.4em;height:.2em;background:#4285f4;
```

Previous version:

```html
<body id=x onload=x.style.fontSize=prompt()+'px'><a b><b l style=padding-left:.5em></b><b y></b><b g></b></a><i style=height:.4em></i><i style="background:#ea4335;border-radius:0 1em 0 0;transform-origin:0%100%;transform:rotate(-45deg)"></i><i b z style=top:.2em;left:.2em;width:.6em;height:.6em></i><i l z style="top:.4em;height:.2em;border-radius:0 2%10%0/0 50%50%0;width:.4em"><style>*{position:relative;background:#fff}a,b,i{display:block;float:left;width:.5em;height:.5em}a{height:1em;width:1em;transform:rotate(45deg);overflow:hidden}i{position:absolute;top:0;left:.5em}[b]{border-radius:50%}[g]{background:#34a853}[l]{background:#4285f4}[y]{background:#fbbc05}[z]{z-index:1
```

Comment: Traitor! (just kidding, nice one ;-) )

Comment: On my browser the old version shows slight gaps between colors, and the new version gives a gradient transition between colors (Firefox 49.0.1 32-bit on Win10 x64)

Comment: @alldayremix hmmm, looks like Firefox needs to have `image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges` instead of `pixelated`. Will add a note to that effect. I quite like the gradient style! :)

Comment: I've modified the header to read "HTML/JS", since you use both HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 20):

### Bash with Imagemagick (but really Postscript), <s>268</s> <s>255</s> 249 bytes

```sh
C=' setrgbcolor 2.5 2.5 2'
A=' arc stroke '
echo "%!PS
122.4 dup scale
.92 .26 .21$C 45 136$A.98 .74 .02$C 135 226$A.20 .66 .33$C 225 316$A.26 .52 .96$C 315 371$A
4.95 2.5 moveto
2.5 2.5 lineto
stroke"|convert - -crop 612x612+0+180 -scale "$1" o.png
```

Doubled the scaling to remove `setlinewidth`, replaced one scale factor with `dup`, and merged a space into the `A` variable (can't with `C` because `$C45` is parsed as "the variable `C45`").

Thanks to joojaa for suggesting these edits!

#### Old Scale, 255 bytes

```sh
C=' setrgbcolor 5 5 4'
A=' arc stroke'
echo "%!PS
61.2 61.2 scale
2 setlinewidth
.92 .26 .21$C 45 136$A
.98 .74 .02$C 135 226$A
.20 .66 .33$C 225 316$A
.26 .52 .96$C 315 371$A
9.9 5 moveto
5 5 lineto
stroke"|convert - -crop 612x612+0+180 -scale "$1" o.png
```

Takes *N* as the lone argument and outputs to o.png.

#### Ungolfed Postscript for Old Scale

```
%!PS
% Scale so default page has width of 10
61.2 61.2 scale
2 setlinewidth
% Red arc
.92 .26 .21 setrgbcolor
5 5 4 45 136 arc
stroke
% Yellow arc
.98 .74 .02 setrgbcolor
5 5 4 135 226 arc
stroke
% Green arc
.20 .66 .33 setrgbcolor
5 5 4 225 316 arc
stroke
% Blue arc
.26 .52 .96 setrgbcolor
5 5 4 315 371 arc
% Blue in-tick
9.9 5 moveto
5 5 lineto
stroke
```

Comment: You can make this shorter by shaving off one char from scale line `61.2 dup scale` you can also add a space in C like `C=' setrgbcolor 5 5 4 '` and shave 4 spaces. If you designed this at half scale then you could omit `2 setlinewidth`

Answer (score 19):

## Perl 5, <strike>486</strike> <strike>477</strike> <strike>476</strike> 450 (+7 for `-MImager` flag) = 457 bytes

I saved a few bytes thanks to Dada by using functional `new` calls and getting rid of parens, and by using `pop` instead of `$ARGV[0]` as well as the final semicolon. I saved some more by putting that `$n=pop` where it's first used, and by using Perl 4 namespace notation with `'` instead of `::`.

```
$i=new Imager xsize=>$n=pop,ysize=>$n;$h=$n/2;$s=$n*.6;$f=$n*.4;$c='color';($b,$r,$y,$g,$w)=map{new Imager'Color"#$_"}qw(4285f4 ea4335 fbbc05 34a853 fff);$i->box(filled=>1,$c,$w);$i->arc($c,$$_[0],r=>$h,d1=>$$_[1],d2=>$$_[2])for[$b,315,45],[$r,225,315],[$y,135,225],[$g,45,135];$i->circle($c,$w,r=>$n*.3,filled=>1);$i->box($c,$b,ymin=>$f,ymax=>$s,xmin=>$h,xmax=>$n*.9,filled=>1);$i->polygon($c,$w,x=>[$n,$n,$s],y=>[0,$f,$f]);$i->write(file=>'g.png')
```

It requires the module [Imager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Imager), which needs to be installed from CPAN. Takes one integer as a command line argument. The image is not anti-aliased, so it's a bit ugly.

Copy the below code into a file g.pl. We need an additional +7 bytes for the `-MImager` flag, but it saves a few bytes because we don't need to `use Imager;`.

```
$ perl -MImager g.pl 200
```

Here are various sizes:

N=10

[image: 10px]

N=100

[image: 100px]

N=200

[image: 200px]

The completely ungolfed code is straight-forward.

```
use Imager;
my $n = $ARGV[0];
my $i = Imager->new( xsize => $n, ysize => $n );

my $blue   = Imager::Color->new('#4285f4');
my $red    = Imager::Color->new('#ea4335');
my $yellow = Imager::Color->new('#fbbc05');
my $green  = Imager::Color->new('#34a853');
my $white  = Imager::Color->new('white');

$i->box( filled => 1, color => 'white' );
$i->arc( color => $blue,   r => $n / 2, d1 => 315, d2 => 45 );     # b
$i->arc( color => $red,    r => $n / 2, d1 => 225, d2 => 315 );    # r
$i->arc( color => $yellow, r => $n / 2, d1 => 135, d2 => 225 );    # y
$i->arc( color => $green,  r => $n / 2, d1 => 45,  d2 => 135 );    # g
$i->circle( color => $white, r => $n * .3, filled => 1 );
$i->box(
    color  => $blue,
    ymin   => $n * .4,
    ymax   => $n * .6,
    xmin   => $n / 2,
    xmax   => $n * .9,
    filled => 1
);
$i->polygon( color => $white, x => [ $n, $n, $n * .6 ], y => [ 0, $n * .4, $n * .4 ] );
$i->write( file => 'g.png' );
```

---

This post previously had the code shaped like the output image. Since that is against the rules for code golf I had to remove it. See the [revision history](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/95999/revisions) if you want to take a look. I used [Acme::EyeDrops](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/Acme::EyeDrops) to create that, with a shape that I created from an image created with the program itself that I converted to ASCII art. The code I obfuscated was already golfed, which can be seen by replacing the first `eval` with a `print`.

Comment: Very nice! Just a few details about the golfing : `pop` instead of `$ARGV[0]`. `$h=($n=pop)/2` instead of `$n=pop;...;$h=$n/2`. `new Imager::Color"#$_"` instead of `Imager::Color->new("#$_")`. (and you forgot to drop the last semicolon). But once again, that's just some small details, your code is really great! (I couldn't have done it! I didn't even know about `Imager`, which is pretty convenient!)

Comment: @Dada thanks. Actually it's pretty straight-forward code. I correct people so much about using the method notation on SO that it's really hard to not do that on purpose. But you're right. This was the first time I used Imager myself. I think I saw it in the Perl Weekly.

Comment: @Dada using `Imager'Color` with the Perl 4 namespace delimiter saves another byte. :)

Comment: Indeed, first time I see a use for that syntax! Also, `-MImager` is shorter than `use Imager;` :)

Comment: @Dada I was going to do that one anyway :P And putting `$n=pop` into the `new` args saves the parens and a semicolon

Answer (score 19):

## MATLAB, <s>189</s> 184 bytes

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(-5:10/(input("")-1):5);[A,R]=cart2pol(-X,Y);I=round(A*2/pi+3);I(R<3)=1;I(X>0&Y.^2<1)=5;I(R>5)=1;image(I)
colormap([1,1,1;[234,67,53;251,188,5;52,168,83;66,133,244]/255])
```

### ungolfed

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(-5:10/(input("")-1):5);    % coordinates in 10th of image width
[A,R]=cart2pol(-X,Y);                     % angle and radius
I=round(A*2/pi+3); % map [0-45,45-135,135-225,225-315,315-360] to [1,2,3,4,5]
I(R<3)=1;                                 % clear inner pixels
I(X>0&Y.^2<1)=5;                          % draw horizontal line
I(R>5)=1;                                 % clear outer pixels
image(I)
colormap([1,1,1;[234,67,53;251,188,5;52,168,83;66,133,244]/255])
```

Answer (score 14):

## PHP + SVG, 300 Bytes

```
<svg width=<?=$_GET["w"]?> viewBox=0,0,10,10><def><path id=c d=M0,5A5,5,0,0,1,5,0V2A3,3,0,0,0,2,5 /></def><?foreach(["fbbc05"=>-45,"ea4335"=>45,"4285f4"=>168.5,"34a853"=>225]as$k=>$v)echo"<use xlink:href=#c fill=#$k transform=rotate($v,5,5) />"?><rect x=5 y=4 fill=#4285f4 width=4.9 height=2 /></svg>
```

The scaling part is `width=<?=$_GET[w]?>`

Output for value 333

```html
<svg width="333" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
<def><path id="c" d="M 0,5 A 5 5 0 0 1 5,0 V 2 A 3,3 0 0 0 2,5"/></def>
<use xlink:href="#c" fill="#fbbc05" transform="rotate(-45,5,5)"/><use xlink:href="#c" fill="#ea4335" transform="rotate(45,5,5)"/><use xlink:href="#c" fill="#4285f4" transform="rotate(168.5,5,5)"/><use xlink:href="#c" fill="#34a853" transform="rotate(225,5,5)"/>
<rect x="5" y="4" fill="#4285f4" width="4.9" height="2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can't you golf the space between the attributes' double quotes(`"`) and the next attribute? E.g. `<svg width="333" viewBox="0 0 10 10">` -> `<svg width="333"viewBox="0 0 10 10">`

Comment: @BojidarMarinov Yes it is corecct it saves a few Bytes. Thank You

Comment: Remove spaces between letters and numbers in path data: `M 0,5 A 5 5 0 0 1 5,0 V 2 A 3,3 0 0 0 2,5` => `M0,5A5 5 0 0 1 5,0V2A3,3 0 0 0 2,5`

Comment: @darrylyeo wonderful idea. Thank You

Comment: Sure. Also, for your `echo` statement, use a double-quoted string to allow inline variables and remove the semicolon: `echo'<use xlink:href="#c"fill="#'.$k.'"transform="rotate($v,5,5)"/>';` => `echo"<use xlink:href='#c'fill='#$k'transform='rotate($v,5,5)'/>"`

Comment: I think most double quotes can be safely removed. Like `<rect x=5 y=4 fill=#4285f4 width=4.9 height=2 />` (Here, you'll need a space before the `/`, though.)

Comment: @Arnauld You are right if the attribute contains no space we can remove the quotes. Thank You

Comment: You can build on that by changing the spaces to commas in the SVG attributes thus allowing you to drop more quotes.

Comment: @Neil Thank You If I read it I remember that

Answer (score 14):

## Logo, 258 bytes

... because I figure **logos should be made using Logo**.  This is implemented as a function.  I developed it using [Calormen.com's online Logo interpreter](http://calormen.com/jslogo/)

I originally attempted to draw each segment and paint fill it, but that turned out to be bigger than expected.  There was a lot of wasted movement backtracking and such.  Instead, I decided to do a polar graph sweep, adjusting the color based on the heading.  The harder part of the math was doing the geometry for the curve at the top of the G's rectangle.  You could trim some decimals and have less accuracy, but I wanted this to be accurate to about 3 digits to accommodate typical screen sizes.

### Golfed

```
to g:n
ht
make"a arctan 1/:n
seth 78.46
repeat 326.54/:a[make"h heading
pu fd:n/2 pd
setpc"#4285f4
if:h>135[setpc"#34a853]if:h>225[setpc"#fbbc05]if:h>315[setpc"#ea4335]bk:n*.2 pu bk:n*.3
rt:a]home bk:n*.1
filled"#4285f4[fd:n/5 rt 90 fd:n*.49 rt 90 fd:n/5]end
```

### Sample

`g 200`
[image: Google logo, size 200px]

### Ungolfed

```
to g :n ; Draw a G of width/height n

hideturtle ; Hide the turtle, since she's not part of the Google logo

;Determine the proper size of the angle to rotate so that the circle stays smooth within 1 px at this size
make "a arctan 1/:n 

setheading 78.46 ; Point toward the top corner of the upcoming rectangle

repeat 326.54 / :a [ ; Scoot around most of the circle, :a degrees at a time

  make"h heading ; Store heading into a variable for golfing purposes

  ; Position pen at the next stroke
  penup 
  forward :n / 2
  pendown

  ; Set the pen color depending on the heading
  setpencolor "#4285f4
  if :h > 135 [ setpencolor "#34a853]
  if :h > 225 [ setpencolor "#fbbc05]
  if :h > 315 [ setpencolor "#ea4335]

  ; Draw the stroke and return to center
  back :n * .2
  penup
  back :n * .3

  right :a ; Rotate to the next sweep heading
]

; Draw the rectangle
home
back :n * .1
filled "#4285f4 [
  forward :n/5
  right 90
  forward :n * .49 ;This is just begging to be :n / 2 but I couldn't bring myself to do it.  Proper math is more like :n * (sqrt 6) / 5
  right 90 
  forward :n / 5
]

end
```

Answer (score 12):

### JavaScript (ES7), <s>285</s> <s>258</s> <s>254</s> <s>252</s> 251 bytes

Prompts for the width of the logo (up to 999) and draws it in a canvas, pixel per pixel.

***Edit***: The initial version was converting Cartesian coordinates `(x,y)` to Polar coordinates `(r,a)`, but we don't really need the angle. It's simpler (and significantly shorter) to just do comparisons between `x` and `y` to find out in which quarter we are.

***Edit***: Saved 1 byte thanks to ETHproductions.

#### JS, <s>251</s> <s>224</s> <s>220</s> <s>218</s> 217 bytes

```js
for(w=x=y=prompt(c=c.getContext`2d`)/2;r=(x*x+y*y)**.5,q=(x<y)+2*(x<-y),c.fillStyle='#'+'4285F434A853EA4335FBBC05FFF'.substr(x>0&r<w&y*y<w*w/25?0:r<w*.6|r>w|!q&y<0?24:q*6,6),x-->-w||y-->-(x=w);)c.fillRect(x+w,y+w,1,1)
```

#### HTML, 34 bytes

```html
<canvas id=c width=999 height=999>
```

#### ES6 version: <s>258</s> <s>231</s> <s>227</s> <s>225</s> 224 + 34 = 258 bytes

Recommended maximum width for the snippet: 190.

```js
for(w=x=y=prompt(c=c.getContext`2d`)/2;r=Math.pow(x*x+y*y,.5),q=(x<y)+2*(x<-y),c.fillStyle='#'+'4285F434A853EA4335FBBC05FFF'.substr(x>0&r<w&y*y<w*w/25?0:r<w*.6|r>w|!q&y<0?24:q*6,6),x-->-w||y-->-(x=w);)c.fillRect(x+w,y+w,1,1)
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=999 height=999>
```

Comment: I looked through the JavaScript part and immediately thought, "What on earth are these `<-` and `-->` operators??" I guess that's what happens when you've been thinking about hypothetical operators for a hypothetical language for 24 hours... :P

Comment: @ETHproductions They're also confusing Notepad++ syntax highlighter which is interpreting `-->` as the start (?) of a html comment if this is put inside `<script>` tags in a html file.

Comment: Believe it or not, Notepad++ is sort of right (though not completely). Check out the very last item in the [ES6 compat table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Comment: @ETHproductions - Wow. I suppose there's a good reason behind this syntax, but I fail to see it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Just so you know, I believe it's only valid at the start of a line. `123 --> comment` throws an error in my browser console (Firefox 49), while `--> comment` does not.

Comment: I think you can save exactly one byte with `'4285F434A853EA4335FBBC05FFF'.substr(x>0&r<w&y*y<w*w/25?0:r<w*.6|r>w|!q&y<0?24:q*6,6)`. It's not as pretty, but it does the job.

Comment: @ETHproductions Well, a byte is a byte. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

### <s>JS/</s>CSS/HTML(+JS), <s>40</s> 0 + <s>701</s> <s>644</s> <s>617</s> 593 + <s>173</s> <s>90</s> <s>97 121 = <s>914</s> <s>774</s> <s>754</s> 730</s> 714 bytes

```css
*{position:absolute}a,h{height:100%;background:#4285F4}a,g{width:100%;border-radius:100%}h{width:30%;height:20%;top:40%}b,c,d,e,f{width:50%;height:50%}b,d,f,h{left:50%}e,f{top:50%}c{border-radius:100% 0 0;background:linear-gradient(45deg,#FBBC05 50%,#EA4335 50%)}d{border-radius:0 100% 0 0;background:linear-gradient(-45deg,transparent 50%,#EA4335 50%)}e{border-radius:0 0 0 100%;background:linear-gradient(-45deg,#34A853 50%,#FBBC05 50%)}f{border-radius:0 0 100%;background:linear-gradient(45deg,#34A853 50%,#4285F4 50%)}b,g{height:40%;background:#FFF}g{width:60%;height:60%;top:20%;left:20%}
```

```html
<input oninput=with(o.style)height=width=value+"px"><o id=o><a></a><b></b><c></c><d></d><e></e><f></f><g></g><h></h></o>
```

Uses linear gradients rather than transforms. Edit: Saved 140 bytes thanks to @darrylyeo. Saved 20 bytes by using an extra element instead of a gradient. Saved 24 bytes thanks to @DBS. Saved 16 bytes thanks to @Hedi. From back to front, the various layers are:

- `a` The blue circle
- `b` A white rectangle to obscure the part above the bar
- `c` The red/yellow top left quarter
- `d` The red octant top right
- `e` The yellow/green bottom left quarter
- `f` The green/blue bottom right quarter
- `g` The inner white circle
- `h` The horizontal blue bar

### JavaScript (ES6) (+SVG), 293 bytes, invalid

```js
document.write(`<svg id=o width=${prompt()} viewbox=0,0,50,50>`);m=`39,11`;`#EA433511,11
#FBBC0511,39
#34A85339,39
#4285F445,25L25,25`.replace(/(.{7})(.{5})(.*)/g,(_,s,t,u)=>m=document.write(`<path stroke=${s} d=M${m}A20,20,0,0,0,${t+u} fill=none stroke-width=10 stroke-linejoin=round />`)||t)
```

Sadly the round line join isn't quite the requested effect, but it's pretty close.

Comment: Instead of IDs, you should use element names such as `a`, `b`, `i`, `s`, etc. Use `*` instead of `div` for the CSS selector.

Comment: Also, use `background` as a shorthand for `background-image`.

Comment: @darrylyeo Thanks, that's made a big difference to my score, not helped by me forgetting even to remove the quotes from my HTML...

Comment: Heh, no problem!

Comment: I believe you could save a few characters here and there by using the compound `border-radius`. E.g. `c{border-radius:100% 0 0;` instead of `c{border-top-left-radius:100%;`

Comment: @DBS I knew I was missing something there, it's obvious now you say it...

Comment: I think you could use this `<input oninput="(s=o.style).height=s.width=value+'px'">`. You don't need `this.` and you don't need to create a function. I don't know if you can remove the double quote in this case.

Answer (score 11):

## C#, 276 + 21 = 297 bytes

276 bytes for method + 21 bytes for System.Drawing import.

```
using System.Drawing;n=>{var q=new Bitmap(n,n);uint W=0xFFFFFFFF,B=0xFF4285F4;for(int y=0,x=0;x<n;y=++y<n?y:x-x++){float a=2f*x/n-1,b=2f*y/n-1,c=b*b;q.SetPixel(x,y,Color.FromArgb((int)(a>0&&a<.8&&c<.04?B:a*a+c>1||a*a+c<.36?W:a*a<c?b<0?0xFFEA4335:0xFF34A853:a<0?0xFFFBBC05:b<-.2?W:B)));}return q;};
```

Based on Martin Rosenau's algorithm. Thanks for doing the hard part of coming up with a way to construct the image!

```
using System.Drawing;             // Import System.Drawing
/*Func<int, Bitmap>*/ n =>
{
    var q = new Bitmap(n, n);     // Create nxn output bitmap
    uint W=0xFFFFFFFF,            // White, color used more than once
         B=0xFF4285F4;            // Blue, color used more than once
    for(int y = 0, x = 0; x < n;  // Loops for(x=0;x<N;x+=1) for(y=0;y<N;y+=1) combined
        y = ++y < n               // Increment y first until it reaches n
            ? y           
            : x - x++)            // Then increment x, resetting y
    {
        float a = 2f * x / n - 1, // Relative coords. Refer to Martin Rosenau's
              b = 2f * y / n - 1, // for what this magic is.
              c = b * b;          // b*b is used more than 3 times

        q.SetPixel(x, y,          // Set pixel (x,y) to the appropriate color
            Color.FromArgb((int)  // Cast uint to int :(
            ( // Here lies magic
                a > 0 && a < .8 && c < .04 
                    ? B
                    : a * a + c > 1 || a * a + c < .36
                        ? W
                        : a * a < c 
                            ? b < 0 
                                ? 0xFFEA4335
                                : 0xFF34A853
                            : a < 0
                                ? 0xFFFBBC05
                                : b < -.2
                                    ? W
                                    : B
            )));
    }
    return q;
};
```

26: [image: 26]

400: [image: 400]

Comment: You can save bytes by not including the transparency in the colour code i.e. `0xFF...`

Answer (score 8):

### Ruby 2.3.1, <strike>376</strike> 359 bytes

Using the RMagick gem.

```
d,f=$*[0].to_i,2.5;g,h,e,c=d-1,d/2,Magick::ImageList.new,Magick::Draw.new;e.new_image(d,d);c.stroke('#EA4335').fill_opacity(0).stroke_width(d*0.2).ellipse(h,h,g/f,g/f,225,315).stroke('#FBBC05').ellipse(h,h,g/f,g/f,135,225).stroke('#34A853').ellipse(h,h,g/f,g/f,45,135).stroke('#4285F4').ellipse(h,h,g/f,g/f,348.5,45).line(h,h,d*0.989,h).draw(e);e.write($*[1])
```

**Examples**

50x50

[image: 50x50]

250x250

[image]

500x500

[image]

1000x1000

[image]

File takes two parameters- the first being the dimension and the second being the filename to save the output as.

**Ungolfed**

```
require "RMagick"

# Take the user's input for dimension
d = $*[0].to_i

e = Magick::ImageList.new
e.new_image(d, d)

c = Magick::Draw.new

# Start by setting the color to red
c.stroke('#EA4335')

  # set opacity to nothing so that we don't get extra color.
  .fill_opacity(0)

  # set thickness of line.
  .stroke_width(d*0.2)

  # #ellipse creates an ellipse taking
  # x, y of center
  # width, height,
  # arc start, arc end
  .ellipse(d / 2, d / 2, (d - 1) / 2.5, (d - 1) / 2.5, 225, 315)

  # change to yellow and draw its portion
  .stroke('#FBBC05')
  .ellipse(d / 2, d / 2, (d - 1) / 2.5, (d - 1) / 2.5, 135, 225)

  # change to green and draw its portion
  .stroke('#34A853')
  .ellipse(d / 2, d / 2, (d - 1) / 2.5, (d - 1) / 2.5, 45, 135)

  # change to blue and draw its portion
  .stroke('#4285F4')
  .ellipse(d / 2, d / 2, (d-1)/2.5, (d - 1)/2.5, 348.5, 45)

  # creates the chin for the G
  .line(d/2, d/2, d*0.99, d/2)

  # draws to the created canvas
  .draw(e)

# save out the file
# taking the filename as a variable saves a byte over
# "a.png"
e.write($*[1])
```

I had initially started solving this using oily_png/chunky_png but that would likely end up far too complicated compared to RMagick. RMagick's .ellipse function made this a breeze and the main work was around tuning the shapes/sizes of everything.

This is my first Code Golf submission(first SE answer also) and I only consider myself somewhat intermediate with Ruby. If you have any input on improvement/tips, please feel free to share!

Comment: I can't seem to edit my post(404 error) but if I were to remove the require line from my golfed solution that'd shave off 17 bytes and bring it down to 359 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>378</s> 373 bytes

I really wanted to do this using `turtle`. I had to dust off my knowledge of Geometry for this, calculating angles and lengths not provided in the challenge description.

*Edit: removed `up()`, since doing so removes the little sliver of white between green and blue and makes the inner circle look better. This slows down the program even more.*

*Edit: replaced `9*n` with `2*n` to make faster. I determined that it would still create a smooth circle.*

```python
from turtle import*
n=input()
C=circle
F=fill
K=color
q=90
w="white"
t=n*.3
lt(45)
def P(c,x,A):K(c);F(1);fd(x);lt(q);C(x,A,2*n);F(0);goto(0,0);rt(q)
for c in"#EA4335","#FBBC05","#34A853":P(c,n/2,q)
P(w,t,360)
K("#4285F4")
F(1)
fd(n/2)
lt(q)
a=11.537
C(n/2,45+a,2*n)
seth(0)
bk(.489*n)
rt(q)
fd(n/5)
lt(q)
fd(t)
F(0)
bk(t)
K(w)
F(1)
fd(.283*n)
lt(94-2*a)
C(t,a-45,2*n)
F(0)
```

**Notes:**

1. The trinkets use Python 3, so the input must be cast to int.
2. The trinkets go *really* slow for large `n` if you remove `speed(0)`, which I added only for speed.
3. The slowness of the code is mostly due to the third parameter of `circle` growing `O(n)`, since it determines how many sides the inscribed polygon for drawing the circle has.

[**Try it online**](https://trinket.io/python/b0501f0e04)

**Ungolfed:** [**Try it online**](https://trinket.io/python/e884ef7a0e)

**Fun fact:** `Trinket` is an anagram of `Tkinter`, Python's GUI package and the foundation for `turtle`.

Comment: Also, if someone has Python installed, could they run it with a large value of `n` for me? If it doesn't look nice, I may need to put some `sqrt`s in there to be more exact. I rounded to the thousandths.

Comment: [Output for 500. Looks fine to me](http://puu.sh/rGEVO/1bff0e5355.png)

Comment: It's only the large values I'm worried about. The canvas on Trinket has a max of 400.

Comment: [Three big triangles appear and then this happens.](http://puu.sh/rGIMg/acdf1e3de2.png)

Comment: @daHugLenny No idea. It might be a memory problem, since 10000 is such a large value.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP + GD, <s>529</s> 449 bytes

This takes a query string parameter `n` and outputs a PNG version of the logo of the specified size.

```
<?php $n=$_GET['n'];$h=$n/2;$c='imagecolorallocate';$a='imagefilledarc';$i=imagecreatetruecolor($n,$n);$m=[$c($i,66,133,244),$c($i,52,168,83),$c($i,251,188,5),$c($i,234,67,53),$c($i,255,255,255)];imagefill($i,0,0,$m[4]);$j=-11.6;foreach([45,135,225,315]as$k=>$e){$a($i,$h,$h,$n,$n,$j,$e,$m[$k],0);$j=$e;}$a($i,$h,$h,$n*.6,$n*.6,0,0,$m[4],0);imagefilledrectangle($i,$h,$h-$n*.1,$h+$h*.98,$h+$h*.2,$m[0]);header('Content-Type:image/png');imagepng($i);
```

Ungolfed:

```
<?php

$n = $_GET['n'];$h=$n/2;
$c = 'imagecolorallocate';$a='imagefilledarc';
$i = imagecreatetruecolor($n,$n);

// Create array of colors
$m=[$c($i,66,133,244),$c($i,52,168,83),$c($i,251,188,5),$c($i,234,67,53),$c($i,255,255,255)];

// Fill background with white
imagefill($i, 0, 0, $m[4]);

// Create four arcs
$j=-11.6;
foreach([45,135,225,315]as$k=>$e){
    $a($i, $h, $h, $n, $n, $j, $e, $m[$k], 0);$j=$e;
}

// Hollow out the center and fill with white
$a($i, $h, $h, $n*.6,$n*.6,0,0,$m[4],0);

// create the horizontal bar
imagefilledrectangle($i,$h,$h-$n*.1,$h+$h*.98,$h+$h*.2,$m[0]);

// Output
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($i);
```

N=13:
[image: 13x13]

N=200:
[image: 200x200]

Comment: Most of the string constants need no quotes. True color image needs no `imagecolorallocate`; just give 0xRRGGBB as color to the drawing functions. Some more golfing and it´s down to 329 bytes: `imagefill($i=imagecreatetruecolor($n=$argv[1],$n),0,0,($m=[4359668,3450963,0xfbbc05,0xea4335,0xffffff])[4]);for($j=-11.6;$e=[45,135,225,315][$k];$j=$e)($a=imagefilledarc)($i,$h=$n/2,$h,$n,$n,$j,$e,$m[$k++],0);$a($i,$h,$h,$n*.6,$n*.6,0,0,$m[4],0);imagefilledrectangle($i,$h,$h-$n*.1,$h+$h*.98,$h+$h*.2,$m[0]);imagepng($i,"g.png");`, run with `-r`, takes input from command line and outputs to `g.png`.

Comment: Sorry my previous golf was two bytes too short: `[$k` has to be `[+$k`. But this one should work as well: `imagefill($i=imagecreatetruecolor($n=$argv[1],$n),0,0,$w=2**24-1);$j=-11.6;foreach([$b=4359668,3450963,0xfbbc05,0xea4335]as$c)($a=imagefilledarc)($i,$h=$n/2,$h,$n,$n,$j,$j=45+90*$k++,$c,0);$a($i,$h,$h,$p=$n*.6,$p,0,0,$w,0);imagefilledrectangle($i,$h,$n*.4,$n*.99,$p,$b);imagepng($i,"g.png");` (291 bytes)

Comment: @Titus Thanks. I found out after this answer that you don't need `imagecolorallocate`. I'll update my answer with your code. But do you need to output to file name? Can't you just leave out the filename in `imagepng` and just have it output to stdout?

Answer (score 5):

## Java, 568 bytes

Not the strongest language for golfing, but here is my earnest attempt:

```java
import java.awt.image.*;class G{public static void main(String[]b)throws Exception{int n=Integer.parseInt(b[0]),x,y,a,c;BufferedImage p=new BufferedImage(n,n,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);for(y=0;y<n;y++){for(x=0;x<n;x++){double u=(x+.5)/n-.5,v=.5-(y+.5)/n,r=Math.hypot(u,v);a=(int)(Math.atan2(v,u)*4/Math.PI);c=0xFFFFFF;if(0<u&u<.4&-.1<v&v<.1)c=0x4285F4;else if(r<.3|r>.5);else if(a==0&v<.1)c=0x4285F4;else if(a==1|a==2)c=0xEA4335;else if(a==-1|a==-2)c=0x34A853;else if(a!=0)c=0xFBBC05;p.setRGB(x,y,c);}}javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(p,"png",new java.io.File("G.png"));}}
```

Usage:

```
> javac G.java
--> Compiles to G.class
> java G 400
--> Writes G.png in current working directory
```

Un-golfed version - the basic idea is to work in the coordinate system u, v ∈ [−0.5, 0.5] and calculate the distance and angle of each pixel from the image center:

```java
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Google {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int[] pixels = new int[n * n];

        for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                double u = (x + 0.5) / n - 0.5;
                double v = 0.5 - (y + 0.5) / n;
                double r = Math.hypot(u, v);
                int a = (int)(Math.atan2(v, u) * 4 / Math.PI);
                int c = 0xFFFFFF;
                if (0 < u && u < 0.4 && Math.abs(v) < 0.1)
                    c = 0x4285F4;
                else if (r < 0.3 || r > 0.5)
                    /*empty*/;
                else if (a == 0 && v < 0.1)
                    c = 0x4285F4;
                else if (a == 1 || a == 2)
                    c = 0xEA4335;
                else if (a == -1 || a == -2)
                    c = 0x34A853;
                else if (a != 0)
                    c = 0xFBBC05;
                pixels[y * n + x] = c;
            }
        }

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(n, n, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        image.setRGB(0, 0, n, n, pixels, 0, n);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("G.png"));
    }

}
```

My implementation computes and draws raw pixels. It is possible to create an alternative implementation that uses high-level graphics routines like [Graphics2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) and [Arc2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Arc2D.html) to do the drawing, especially with anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, 141

```
ri:M.5*:K5/:T;'P3NMSMN255NM2m*[K.5-_]f.-{:X:mh:IK>0{X~0<\zT>|{IT3*<0{X~>X~W*>:Z2+{Z{X0=TW*>}4?}?}?}1?}?}%"^^G_8:nEhB%P9IW@zA"102b256b3/f=:+N*
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%3AM.5*%3AK5%2F%3AT%3B%27P3NMSMN255NM2m*%5BK.5-_%5Df.-%7B%3AX%3Amh%3AIK%3E0%7BX%7E0%3C%5CzT%3E%7C%7BIT3*%3C0%7BX%7E%3EX%7EW*%3E%3AZ2%2B%7BZ%7BX0%3DTW*%3E%7D4%3F%7D%3F%7D%3F%7D1%3F%7D%3F%7D%25%22%5E%5EG_8%3AnEhB%25P9IW%40zA%22102b256b3%2Ff%3D%3A%2BN*&input=40)

Outputs the image in ASCII ppm format.
For an ASCII-art version that's nicer to look at in the browser, try [this code](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%3AM.5*%3AK5%2F%3AT%3BM2m*%5BK.5-_%5Df.-%7B%3AX%3Amh%3AIK%3E0%7BX%7E0%3C%5CzT%3E%7C%7BIT3*%3C0%7BX%7E%3EX%7EW*%3E%3AZ2%2B%7BZ%7BX0%3DTW*%3E%7D4%3F%7D%3F%7D%3F%7D1%3F%7D%3F%7D%25M%2FN*&input=40). It helps visualize the algorithm too.

**Explanation:**

```
ri:M                 read input, convert to int and store in M
.5*:K                multiply by 0.5 and store in K (M/2)
5/:T;                divide by 5 and store in T (M/10) and pop
'P3NMSMN255N         ppm header (N=newline, S=space)
M2m*                 generate all pixel coordinates - pairs of numbers 0..M-1
[K.5-_]              push the center (coordinates K-0.5, K-0.5)
f.-                  subtract the center from every pixel
{…}%                 map (transform) the array of coordinate pairs
  :X                 store the current pair in X
  :mh:I              calculate the hypotenuse of X (distance from the center)
                      and store in I
  K>0                if I>K (outside the big circle), push 0
  {…}                else…
    X~               dump X's coordinates (row, column)
    0<               check if the column is <0
    \zT>|            or the absolute value of the row is >T
    {…}              if true (outside the G bar)…
      IT3*<0         if I<T*3 (inside the small circle) push 0
      {…}            else (between the circles)…
        X~>          dump X and check if row>column (diagonal split)
        X~W*>:Z      also check if row>-column (other diagonal) and store in Z
                      (W=-1)
        2+           if in lower-left half, push Z+2 (2 for left, 3 for bottom)
        {…}          else (upper-right half)…
          Z{…}       if it's in the right quadrant
            X0=      get the row coordinate of X
            TW*>     compare with -T, resulting in 0 (above the bar) or 1
          4          else (top quadrant) push 4
          ?          end if
        ?            end if
      ?              end if
    1                else (inside the G bar) push 1
    ?                end if
  ?                  end if
"^^G … @zA"          push a string containing the 5 colors encoded
102b                 convert from base 102 to a big number
                      (ASCII values of chars are treated as base-102 digits)
256b                 convert to base 256, splitting into 15 bytes
3/                   split into triplets (RGB)
f=                   replace each generated number (0..4)
                      with the corresponding color triplet
:+N*                 join all the triplets, and join everything with newlines
```

Answer (score 4):

### Go, 379 bytes

```go
import ."fmt"
func f(a int)(s string){
m:=map[string]float64{"fbbc05":-45,"ea4335":45,"4285f4":168.5,"34a853":225}
for k,v:=range m{s+=Sprintf("<use xlink:href=#c fill=#%v transform=rotate(%v,5,5) />",k,v)}
return Sprintf("<svg width=%v viewBox=0,0,10,10><def><path id=c d=M0,5A5,5,0,0,1,5,0V2A3,3,0,0,0,2,5 /></def>%v<rect x=5 y=4 fill=#4285f4 width=4.9 height=2 /></svg>",a,s)}
```

The function `f` takes a single `int` argument (the scale factor) and outputs an SVG image scaled appropriately.

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/fork/z5vIdp) at Ideone.

Example output:

```html
<svg width=333 viewBox=0,0,10,10><def><path id=c d=M0,5A5,5,0,0,1,5,0V2A3,3,0,0,0,2,5 /></def><use xlink:href=#c fill=#34a853 transform=rotate(225,5,5) /><use xlink:href=#c fill=#fbbc05 transform=rotate(-45,5,5) /><use xlink:href=#c fill=#ea4335 transform=rotate(45,5,5) /><use xlink:href=#c fill=#4285f4 transform=rotate(168.5,5,5) /><rect x=5 y=4 fill=#4285f4 width=4.9 height=2 /></svg>
```

It seems wrong to appease our Google overlords in any programming language except their own.

Answer (score 3):

## FreeMarker+HTML/CSS, 46 + 468 = 514 bytes

HTML:

```
<div><div></div><div></div><span></span></div>
```

CSS:

```
div div,div span{position:absolute}div{width:10px;height:10px;box-sizing:border-box;transform-origin:top left;position:relative;transform:scale(${n*.1})}div div{border:2px solid;border-radius:9px;border-color:transparent #4285f4 transparent transparent;transform:rotate(33.4630409671deg);transform-origin:center}div div+div{border-color:#ea4335 transparent #34a853 #fbbc05;transform:none}div span{display:block;top:4px;bottom:4px;left:5px;right:.1px;background:#4285f4}
```

Assuming the FreeMarker processor is executed with a variable `n` set, representing input.

### Explanation of magic numbers:

Everything is based on a 10x10px wrapper, then scaled by `n/10`.

- Distance to right of blue horizontal box [px]: 5 - sqrt(5^2 - 1^2) = **0.10102051443** ([Pythagoras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem))
- Rotation of blue arc [deg]: 45 - arcSin(1/5) = **33.4630409671** ([Sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine))

### [Ungolfed JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5kbp9vj/10/)

Comment: Put the CSS Part in a style element and use Javascript or PHP. replace `transform:scale(n)` with `transform:scale(<?=$_GET[n])?>` (PHP). In javascript you can append the CSS Part to the style Element

Comment: I thought about JS but didn't want to spoil the code too much. However, templating languages seem ok, so I went with FreeMarker and quickly adjusted my answer, thanks.

Comment: The blue bar is too far to the right on the right side it think

Comment: No, you can easily calculate it by imagining a right triangle with side lengths 0.5, 0.1 and x, where x denotes the blue bar's width, or accordingly 0.5-x its distance to the right. x can then be determined by using Pythagoras' theorem (see the explanations I added).

Comment: The JSFiddle doesn't display correctly in the two browsers I've tried (Win10 x64) -- with Chrome 54.0.2840.59 m (64-bit) the blue bar extends too far to the right, and with Firefox 49.0.1 (32-bit) there is a slight gap midway through the blue curved part

Comment: @alldayremix, I could now reproduce your issue in Chrome (not FF though). The problem is that the renderer seems to snap borders into pixels before applying scaling, so sub-pixel scales don't work. But I'd consider this an inaccuracy of the rendering engine.

Answer (score 3):

## 343 octets of Haskell

```
roman@zfs:~$ cat ppmG.hs
ppmG n='P':unlines(map show([3,n,n,255]++concat[
 case map signum[m^2-(2*x-m)^2-(2*y-m)^2,
 (10*x-5*m)^2+(10*y-5*m)^2-(3*m)^2,
 m-x-y,x-y,5*y-2*m,3*m-5*y,2*x-m]of
 1:1:1:1:_->[234,67,53]
 1:1:1:_->[251,188,5]
 [1,_,_,_,1,1,1]->[66,133,244]
 1:1:_:1:1:_->[66,133,244]
 1:1:_:_:1:_->[52,168,83]
 _->[255,255,255]|m<-[n-1],y<-[0..m],x<-[0..m]]))
roman@zfs:~$ wc ppmG.hs
 10  14 343 ppmG.hs
roman@zfs:~$ ghc ppmG.hs -e 'putStr$ppmG$42'|ppmtoxpm
ppmtoxpm: (Computing colormap...
ppmtoxpm: ...Done.  5 colors found.)

/* XPM */
static char *noname[] = {
/* width height ncolors chars_per_pixel */
"42 42 6 1",
/* colors */
"  c #4285F4",
". c #EA4335",
"X c #FBBC05",
"o c #34A853",
"O c #FFFFFF",
"+ c None",
/* pixels */
"OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO",
"OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO............OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO",
"OOOOOOOOOOOO..................OOOOOOOOOOOO",
"OOOOOOOOOO......................OOOOOOOOOO",
"OOOOOOOOO........................OOOOOOOOO",
"OOOOOOOO..........................OOOOOOOO",
"OOOOOOO............................OOOOOOO",
"OOOOOOXX..........................OOOOOOOO",
"OOOOOXXXX........................OOOOOOOOO",
"OOOOXXXXXX.......OOOOOOOO.......OOOOOOOOOO",
"OOOXXXXXXXX....OOOOOOOOOOOO....OOOOOOOOOOO",
"OOOXXXXXXXXX.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOO",
"OOXXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO",
"OOXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO",
"OOXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO",
"OXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO",
"OXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO",
"OXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOO                    O",
"OXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOO                    O",
"OXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOO                    O",
"OXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOO                    O",
"OXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOO                    O",
"OXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOO                    O",
"OXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOO                    O",
"OXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOO                    O",
"OXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO         O",
"OXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO         O",
"OOXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO         OO",
"OOXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO         OO",
"OOXXXXXXXXXXOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO          OO",
"OOOXXXXXXXXooOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOoo        OOO",
"OOOXXXXXXXoooooOOOOOOOOOOOOooooo       OOO",
"OOOOXXXXXooooooooOOOOOOOOoooooooo     OOOO",
"OOOOOXXXoooooooooooooooooooooooooo   OOOOO",
"OOOOOOXoooooooooooooooooooooooooooo OOOOOO",
"OOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOO",
"OOOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOO",
"OOOOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOO",
"OOOOOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOOO",
"OOOOOOOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooOOOOOOOOOOOO",
"OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooooooooooOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO",
"OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"
};
```

### Explanation

- "P3" == [plaintext portable pixmap](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html)
- [show](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:show) == produce ASCII decimals fearing UTF-8 corruption for "\xFF\xFF\xFF"
- [unlines](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:unlines) == separate decimals into lines
- m = n-1 for symmetry in n==length[0..m]
- m²-(2x-m)²-(2y-m)²>0 == (x-m/2)² + (y-m/2)² < (m/2)² == insideOuterCircle
- (10x-5m)²+(10y-5m)²-(3m)²>0 == (x-m/2)² + (y-m/2)² > (m3/10)² == outsideInnerCircle
- m-x-y>0 == x+y < m == inUpperLeft
- x-y>0 == x > y == inUpperRight
- 5y-2m>0 == y > m2/5 == belowGbarTop
- 3y-5y>0 == y < m3/5 == aboveGbarBot
- 2x-m>0 == x > m/2 == inRightHalf
- [234,67,53] == red
- [251,188,5] == yellow
- [52,168,83] == green
- [66,13,244] == blue
- [255,255,255] == white

Comment: Unless you encode it all with 7-bit ASCII _(which you could do since the highest character codepoint you're using is `0x7C`/`124`/`|`)_ in which case it would be **338 septets of Haskell**.  But considering how standard 8-bits-to-a-byte has become in _data storage_ in the last couple of decades, I think the term “bytes” is specific enough without beating the dead horse.

Answer (score 3):

## SAS - <s>590</s> <s>536</s> 521 bytes

This uses the [GTL Annotation facility](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/67909/HTML/default/p1wi4yti5mcg06n1ss0onifod94t.htm). Input is specified in a macro variable on the first line. For a few extra bytes you can define the whole thing as a macro. It still sneaks in below Java and a few of the HTML answers, even though you have to define a null graph template just to be able to plot anything at all!

I've left the line breaks in for a modicum of readability, but I'm not counting those towards the total as it works without them.

```
%let R=;
%let F=FILLCOLOR;
ods graphics/width=&R height=&R;
proc template;
define statgraph a;
begingraph;
annotate;
endgraph;
end;
data d;
retain FUNCTION "RECTANGLE" DISPLAY "FILL" DRAWSPACE "graphPERCENT";
length &F$8;
_="CX4285F4";
P=100/&R;
HEIGHT=P;
width=P;
do i=1to &R;
x1=i*P;
U=x1-50;
do j=1to &R;
y1=j*P;
V=y1-50;
r=euclid(U,V);
&F="";
if 30<=r<=50then if V>U then if V>-U then &F="CXEA4335";
else &F="CXFBBC05";
else if V<-U then &F="CX34A853";
else if V<10then &F=_;
if &F>'' then output;
end;
end;
x1=65;
y1=50;
width=30;
height=20;
&F=_;
output;
proc sgrender sganno=d template=a;
```

**Edit:** shaved off a few more bytes via use of macro vars, default settings and choice of operators.

**Edit 2:** got rid of the `do-end` blocks for the `if-then-else` logic and it somehow still works - I don't entirely understand how. Also, I discovered the `euclid` function!

Answer (score 2):

## SCSS - 415 bytes

Takes input as `$N: 100px;` and `<div id="logo"></div>`, not sure if these should count in the total though...

```
$d:$N*.6;$b:$d/3;#logo{width:$d;height:$d;border:$b solid;border-color:#ea4335 transparent #34a853 #fbbc05;border-radius:50%;position:relative;&:before,&:after{content:'';position:absolute;right:-$b;top:50%;border:0 solid transparent}&:before{width:$b*4;height:$d/2;border-width:0 $b $b 0;border-right-color:#4285f4;border-bottom-right-radius:50% 100%}&:after{width:$N/2;margin:-$b/2 0;border-top:$b solid #4285f4}}
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q93dtgwr/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) with [JuicyPixels](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels) package, 306 bytes

```hs
import Codec.Picture
p=PixelRGB8
c=fromIntegral
b=p 66 133 244
w=p 255 255 255
(n%x)y|y<=x,x+y<=n=p 234 67 53|y>x,x+y<=n=p 251 188 5|y>x,x+y>n=p 52 168 83|y>=0.4*n=b|1>0=w
(n#x)y|d<=h,d>=0.3*n=n%x$y|x>=h,d<=h,abs(y-h)<=n/10=b|1>0=w where h=n/2;d=sqrt$(x-h)^2+(y-h)^2
f n=generateImage(\x y->c n#c x$c y)n n
```

Usage example:

```hs
main = writePng "google.png" $ f 1001
```

This could probably be improved. The idea is to pass a function to `generateImage` that selects the pixel (color really) that should go at position x, y. For that we use a lambda that adds `n` as a parameter and converts them all to floats at the same time. The `#` function basically checks if we're in the ring, the bar, or neither. If it's the ring we pass the baton to `%`, if the bar we just return blue, otherwise white. `%` checks which quadrant we're in and returns the appropriate color if it isn't blue. Blue is a special case since we need to make sure it doesn't wrap around to the red, so we only return blue if `y` is below the "bar line" otherwise we return white. That's the general overview.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript + HTML, 241 bytes

228 bytes for JavaScript + 13 bytes for HTML

```js
(
// code start
n=>{with(c.getContext`2d`)['#4285f4','#34a853','#fbbc05','#ea4335'].map((c,i)=>{beginPath(fillStyle=strokeStyle=c,lineWidth=n/5,a=Math.PI/2);arc(h=n/2,h,r=n*.4,j=i*a-a/2,j+a);stroke();i||clearRect(0,0,n,r)+fillRect(h,r,r,n/5)})}
// code end
)(100);
```

```html
<canvas id=c>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Processing.py - 244 bytes + 1 byte for number of digits in N

Let's start with the code. This can be pasted in the Processing environment and ran (changing `N` for different sizes).

```
N=400
n=N/2
f=fill
a=['#34A853','#FBBC05','#EA4335','#4285F4']
def setup():
 size(N,N);noStroke()
def draw():
 for i in 1,3,5,7: f(a[i/2]);arc(n,n,N,N,i*PI/4+[0,.59][i>6],(i+2)*PI/4)
 f(205);ellipse(n,n,.6*N,.6*N);f(a[3]);rect(n,n-.1*N,.98*n,.2*N)
```

Small cheat: the circle that *cut's out* a part from the logo is drawn in Processing's grayscale shade 205, which is the default background color. Exporting this to an image wouldn't look the same. This saves a call to `background(255)`.

#### Explanation

```
N=400                 # set size
n=N/2                 # precompute center point
f=fill                # 3 usages, saves 3 bytes
a=['#34A853','#FBBC05','#EA4335','#4285F4']
                      # list of colors
def setup():          # called when starting sketch
 size(N,N)            # set size
 noStroke()           # disable stroking
def draw():           # drawing loop
 for i in 1,3,5,7:    # loop over increments of PI/4
  f(a[i/2])           # set fill color using integer
                      # division
  arc(n,n,N,N,i*PI/4+[0,.59][i>6],(i+2)*PI/4)
                      # draw a pizza slice between
                      # two coordinates. The 
                      #     [0,.59][i>6]
                      # accounts for the white part
 f(205)               # set fill color to Processing's
                      # default background
 ellipse(n,n,.6*N,.6*N)
                      # cut out center
 f(a[3])              # set fill to blue
 rect(n,n-.1*N,.98*n,.2*N)
                      # draw the straight part
```

### Examples

`N` = 400

[image: N=400]

`N` = 13 (Processing's minimum size is 100x100)

[image]

### Note

If we allow us to manually edit in multiple values for `N` the explicit calls to `setup` and `draw` are not needed and it is down to 213 bytes + 3 bytes per digit in `N`.

```
N=200
size(200,200)
n=N/2
f=fill
a=['#34A853','#FBBC05','#EA4335','#4285F4']
noStroke()
for i in 1,3,5,7:f(a[i/2]);arc(n,n,N,N,i*PI/4+[0,.59][i>6],(i+2)*PI/4)
f(205);ellipse(n,n,.6*N,.6*N);f(a[3]);rect(n,n-.1*N,.98*n,.2*N)
```

Comment: By itself, this is not a full program

Comment: Fair enough. I removed the incomplete program and substituted it for a complete version.